# Best way to implement an external API in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to call an external API via HTTP to get some data in the form of JSON. This data will be saved to a database pattern defined with the Eloquent ORM. This API requires authentication (by token) and then accepts calls with GET, POST is not needed. The parameters are added to the URL (e.g. ?origin=LHR&destination=GHA).

I'm trying to find a Laravel way to access such data easily - just writing a basic class that has a function with all parameters doesn't seem right. I'd much rather have some sort of query builder, but for the URL. I looked at repositories, but that seems to be geared towards database calls.

To sum up: is there any good "Laravel way" to call an external API?

Comment: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle?

Comment: I was more so referring to extracting the data layer from the controller - I want to define the API structure somewhere and do all the handling there too (like a model in Eloquent) and the controller just "gets" the data.

Comment: IMHO, writing a simple class that mirrors your remote API is clearer for someone reading your code. You can isolate all the details of the API (token authentication, building URLs, making requests, etc.) in the class, then test the heck out of it before integrating it into your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dene something like this just few days ago;

My solution was to define array GET params. F.a.

```
get-some-stuff?where[foo]=bar&with[relation]&with[otherRelation]
```

Then you can get the params via `Input::get()` and go through them with an foreach.

F.a.

```
foreach(Input::get() as $method => $value) { ...
```

In the foreach you could decide what to do based on `$method`

Comment: Marking this as answer, I ended up making an extra class that provides all necessary functions and just gave every function an `$options` array parameter.